# Windows 10 Display / Nvidia detects, then loses connection to monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, displayport

I purchased a new monitor but am having connectivity issues. Both Windows 10 Display and the NVIDIA Control Panel will detect the connection, then lose the connection to the monitor every few seconds (gifs below).

**Is this a faulty monitor, or is it possible to fix this with software?**

The problem only seems to occur on the Display Port connector.  If I run the display port cable through an adapter into the 2nd monitor's mini display port, then Windows detects the monitor just fine.

[image]

---

[image]

---

**Update:** Looking around the internets, there have been some reports of faulty display port controllers for this model (Asus PA278QV).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a hardware problem.  Couldn't find a way to solve this with software alone; had to order a replacement.